# Chart Symbols and Legend Symbols Are Diferent in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, plot, swiftui, charts, line

Legend symbols produced by the .symbol(by:) modifier are different than the ones used in the chart. I specifically used the triangle and plus symbols in the chart, but they are disregarded and the circle and square symbols are produced automatically in the legend part. How can I make them agree?

```
struct Line: Identifiable {
    let xyzipped: [(Double, Double)]
    let symbol: BasicChartSymbolShape
    let legendStr: String
    let id = UUID()
    
    init(x: [Double],
         y: [Double],
         symbol: BasicChartSymbolShape,
         legendStr: String)
    {
        self.xyzipped = Array(zip(x, y))
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.legendStr = legendStr
    }
}


struct ChartOfLines: View {
    let lines: [Line]
    
    init() {
        let line1 = Line(x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                         y: [3, 5, 8, -1, 0],
                         symbol: BasicChartSymbolShape.triangle,
                         legendStr: "line1")
        let line2 = Line(x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                         y: [5, 4, 3, 7, 1],
                         symbol: BasicChartSymbolShape.plus,
                         legendStr: "line2")
        
        lines = [line1, line2]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart(lines, id: \.id) { line in
            ForEach(line.xyzipped, id:\.0) { xy in
                LineMark(
                    x: .value("X values", xy.0),
                    y: .value("Y values", xy.1)
                )
                .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 0.5))
                
                PointMark(
                    x: .value("X values", xy.0),
                    y: .value("Y values", xy.1)
                )
            }
            .symbol(line.symbol)
            .symbol(by: .value("", line.legendStr))
            .foregroundStyle(by: .value("", line.legendStr))
        }
        .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Here is the produced chart:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom `chartLegend` if you want the `ChartSymbolShape` to appear to the left of the legend string:

Example to test, adjust UI as necessary:

```swift
struct Line: Identifiable {
    let xyzipped: [(Double, Double)]
    let symbol: BasicChartSymbolShape
    let legendStr: String
    let lineColor: Color
    let id = UUID()
    
    init(x: [Double],
         y: [Double],
         symbol: BasicChartSymbolShape,
         legendStr: String,
         lineColor: Color)
    {
        self.xyzipped = Array(zip(x, y))
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.legendStr = legendStr
        self.lineColor = lineColor
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    let lines: [Line]
    
    init() {
        let line1 = Line(x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                         y: [3, 5, 8, -1, 0],
                         symbol: BasicChartSymbolShape.triangle,
                         legendStr: "line1", lineColor: .green)
        let line2 = Line(x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                         y: [5, 4, 3, 7, 1],
                         symbol: BasicChartSymbolShape.plus,
                         legendStr: "line2", lineColor: .blue)
        
        
        lines = [line1, line2]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart(lines, id: \.id) { line in
            ForEach(line.xyzipped, id:\.0) { xy in
                LineMark(
                    x: .value("X values", xy.0),
                    y: .value("Y values", xy.1)
                )
                .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 0.5))
                .foregroundStyle(line.lineColor)
                
                PointMark(
                    x: .value("X values", xy.0),
                    y: .value("Y values", xy.1)
                )
                .foregroundStyle(line.lineColor)
            }
            .symbol(line.symbol)
            .foregroundStyle(by: .value("", line.legendStr))
        }
        .chartLegend(position: .bottomLeading, alignment: .bottomLeading) {
            HStack() {
                ForEach(lines) { xy in
                    HStack {
                        xy.symbol
                            .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                            .foregroundColor(xy.lineColor)
                        Text(xy.legendStr).foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for a clear and short answer. This solution works, however, it leaves little space for the plotting area when the legend position .leading or .trailing is chosen. The default behavior of .chartLegend tiles the symbols on different lines for these positions, which is nice, but unfortunately, it does not care about user-specified symbols.